# Trying to insert cyrillic symbols to mysql table

Tags: mysql, jsp, unicode, utf-8, cyrillic

could you please help with troubleshooting issue.

I'm trying to insert cyrillic symbols from jsp to mysql table. Seems, i've tried everything. It actually happened when i've changed method 'GET' on 'POST' of input form.

I've made DB connection pool in NetBeans and here is my URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBSite?useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [DBSite_user on Default schema]
```

I've added filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

     request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
     response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

It changed this symbols  Ð¿Ð¿Ð¿Ð¿ on that ??????. So, it works a bit.

I've added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

If I'm adding cyrillic text to MySQL by MySQL Workbench - everything is OK.

When I do mistake in SQL Update(deliberately) I can see in error message that HTML trying to send cyrillic 'вара', but in fact mysql inserting '????'

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 

     insert into Comments(commentп, date_creation, id_title)
     values ('вара',STR_TO_DATE('23-07-2018 17:52:07', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), 31);

     : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, date_creation, id_title)
     values ('????',STR_TO_DATE('23-07-2018 17:52:07' at line 1
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, date_creation, id_title)
     values ('????',STR_TO_DATE('23-07-2018 17:52:07' at line 1
```

I will appreciate if you help me find where it is changed, in what moment. And how can I debug it at least(server log, for example)? By the way, I'm using NetBeans and GlassFish.

Answer (score 0):

`Ð¿Ð¿Ð¿Ð¿` should be `pe pe pe pe`?  Well, that is [mojibake](http://enwp.org/mojibake).  See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38363566) for a list of things that probably helped cause it.

Question marks have a different cause, also discussed there.

And this might be needed when using POST:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

See if you can get the hex encoding of the text.

Comment: adding accept-charset="UTF-8" does't help. It looks like i've missed something in connection to MySQL.

Comment: @TatyanaTatyana - Spell out the various things indicated in the 'Trouble...' link.